# Difference between custom font and system font?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, core-text

I am using **core text** to draw a string based on content length and I am using **CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString**

Is there any difference between a custom font and the system font?

I am adding attribute **kCTFontAttributeName** to **NSMutableAttributedString**. Each font is not working the same way... When I use systemFont it updates the view very quickly, but if I use the custom font included in plist, it's taking a long time to update the view.

```
    if (self.text != nil)
    {

        self.attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text];
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [self.text length]);
        // Regarding Fixed font
        //        [ self.attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TAUN_Elango_Abirami" size:20] range:range];//This is my custom font


        // Regarding custom Font using below code
        if (self.font != nil) {


             //************************* working fine only system font *******************
//            UIFont *fonts = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24 weight:0];
//            [self.attributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName
//                                          value:fonts
//                                          range:range];

          //  self.font is a custom font from superclass

            //************************* here i am facing problem *******************
            [self.attributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName
                                          value:self.font
                                          range:range];
        }
    }
```

Why is it taking more time when I use **Custom UIFont**?